# PUT request not updating MongoDB

Tags: jquery, node.js, mongodb, express, postman

**Hello Guys**
I´m rookie in programming and I got stuck with this...

I´m working on simple single page ToDo "app" in node, with mongo. I can add new ToDo, delete it, but when I click one to make it completed, it´s not working.

**Simple mongoose schema**

```
let todoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: 'Název musí být uveden!'
    },
    completed: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    created_date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
})
```

**Routing through "helpers"**

```
router.route("/")
    .get(helpers.getTodos)
    .post(helpers.createTodo);


router.route("/:todoId")
    .get(helpers.getTodo)
    .put(helpers.updateTodo)
    .delete(helpers.deleteTodo);
```

in helpers I got update function:

```
exports.updateTodo = function(req, res) {
    db.Todo.findOneAndUpdate({
            id: req.params.todoId
        }, req.body, {
            new: true
        })
        .then(function(todo) {
            res.json(todo);
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            res.send(err);
        });
};
```

When I send PUT request with Postman, to update completed to true, postman returns null...[Postman put request image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MB7LN.jpg)

Because I´m new to this, **I thought that there is something wrong with my ajax**, but then I tried Postman, which returns null and I don´t know what´s wrong.

```
function updateTodo(todo) {
    let updateUrl = "/api/todos/" + todo.data("id");
    let isDone = !todo.data("completed");
    let updateData = {
        completed: isDone
    };

    $.ajax({
        method: "PUT",
        url: updateUrl,
        data: updateData
    }).then(function(updatedTodo) {
        todo.toggleClass("done");
        todo.data("completed", isDone);
    });
}
```

When I click on one, it changes class, terminal in my VS Code shows this:

```
Mongoose: todos._findAndModify(
{ id: '5e78a9ed4d68762accc14a7f' },
[], 
{ '$set': { completed: true } }, 
{ new: true, upsert: false, remove: false, projection: {} })
```

But when I refresh, it´s unchanged

Comment: Hi Tomas, did the ajax call reach your route? You could do a console.log inside your function updateToDo = function(req,res){ console.log('Reached updateToDo);} to check. This can give you a huge clue as to whether your ajax call is working the right way.

Comment: Hey Codey, it works well, it´s changing class to done, with line-through. But when I refresh page, it´s back to default.
And when I try Postman PUT request, it returns null